# I can't connect to FreeSSHd server with Putty

Tags: putty, freesshd

I have Windwos VPS and i want to connect to it with Putty. On the VPS i installed FreeSSHd and created a user account and set the account to public key authorization. On my PC i am running Windows 7 and when i start Putty and enter the user name and then the passphrase the command line window just exits without any messages.
Then when i look in the FreeSSHd log on the VPS i see this:

IP xx.xx.xx SSH user_name successfully logged on using public key.
Shell service granted to user user_name.
IP xx.xx.xx SSH user_name disconnected.

It seems that the connection is breaking down right after i login.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to connect with putty with ssh protocol on win 2ooo workstation running freesshd. I discovered an error in putty.log not in freesshd.log:
"Could not attach console. Kernel API not found." It seems that freesshd tryes to attach to a console and cannot find Kernel API. I wonder if it can be instructed to use other console (maybe I have to write cmd explicitly).